# Incorrect page width in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Width of the page in my Сhrome is fractional and 0.2px larger than the width that Сhrome uses when measuring media queries. This breaks layout at the top point of 'max-width' breakpoints. My colleagues don't have this problem in their browsers. Disabling Сhrome extensions didn't help.

Have you any idea what the problem could be?

[image]